# Is it permissible for Muslims to join groups like Freemasonry?

Tags: halal-haram, christianity, friendship

Two of my brothers are from Turkey, Muslim, and are also Freemasons.  I am Christian and sometimes Christianity does not accept joining and sometimes forbids people from joining the fraternity.  They are great men, intelligent, and faithful to their religion.  Case in point, I had <strike>brats</strike> bratwurst sausages (سجق = نقانق) and burgers during a cookout at my house and they wouldn't eat the brats because of the pork.  We also enjoy each other's company and discuss the differences and similarities of our faiths.  Something which I believe we need more of in society.  Freemasonry has united us as true friends even though we may have remained in perpetual distance otherwise.  However, I am concerned that other Muslims may not appreciate their decision to join.  Are there any common beliefs or stands in Islam against (or for) fraternities such as Freemasonry?

Just as a side note: in one of the groups which we belong, there are people who practice Judaism, Christianity (different denominations), and Islam.  Where else can people of different faiths come together, discuss, and enjoy each other's company?

---

**Please note that the information below is not enough information to answer the question.**  It is just an introduction for those who may not know anything at all about the organization.  I am specifically looking for reasons why Muslims should or should not join groups such as Freemasonry which are multi-faith groups that promote virtues.

- Freemasonry is one of the oldest and largest fraternal societies in
  the world.
- It provides you with a code of living in today's community, based on
  good moral and ethical standards.
- It is an organisation of men who try to live by the principles of
  integrity and goodwill which unifies them, regardless of colour,
  creed or worldly status.
- It is a non profit making organisation that is involved in supporting
  charity and service to the community.
- It provides you with a common interest where you can meet and enjoy
  the company of like minded men from all walks of life.

When a Mason is initiated into the fraternity, he chooses the Holy Book of his choice to use - which is opened during the initiation as a symbol of the rules and guide he chooses to live by.  Freemasonry has many "side bodies" which include groups such as the Shriners, which appear associated with Islam but are not. I find it best described here:

> Despite its theme, the Shrine is not connected to Islam. The Shrine's
>   charitable arm is the Shriners Hospitals for Children, a network of
>   twenty-two hospitals in the United States, Mexico and Canada. They
>   specialize in orthopedic care, burn treatment, cleft lip and palate
>   care and spinal cord injury rehabilitation. All treatment offered at
>   Shriner's Hospitals for Children is offered without any financial
>   obligation to patients and their families, and there is no requirement
>   for religion, race, or relationship to a Shriner. Patients must be
>   under the age of eighteen and treatable.
>
> In 2008, Shriners Hospitals had a total budget of $826 million and in
>   2007 they approved 39,454 new patient applications, attended to the
>   needs of 125,125 patients.

**Edit**
After reading some more questions on this site, I realize that my question is very similar to [this one](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/225/is-it-haraam-to-have-non-muslim-friends?rq=1) - but not quite a duplicate.

Here is some more information from a Muslim who is also a Freemason: http://www.freemasons-freemasonry.com/islam_freemasonry.html

Comment: Many of us who might be able to answer this question don't know much about Freemasonry at all. Can you add something about that to the question?

Comment: @DanAndrews I think this will answer you http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freemasonry#Islam_and_Freemasonry

Comment: @HaLaBi Thanks for the link.  I was looking for something a little more formal and quotes from the Qur'an to back it up.  You can't always trust wikipedia.  The paragraph also mentioned "Saddam Hussein", whom I would not consider a Islamic Patron.

Comment: I re-read the question, I am not sure but I think the information you provided in the question is not enough to give a full answer... You have mentioned only what seems good about free masonry... There might be more good stuff.. but also there might be negative stuff..

Comment: @HaLaBi since "positive" stuff and "negative" stuff is an opinion, I am afraid that I cannot add more.  Are you only looking for bad stuff?  The reason why some Christians do not like Freemasonry is because that it allows people of any religion to join.  Some Christians feel that other Christians should not associate with or belong to groups which allow other religions.  Is Islam similar?

Comment: Well, I told you this information will not be enough to give _full answer_.. I think people can give you an answer to the stuff you mentioned.. free masonry is surrounded by a lot of rumors.. I am a Muslim and I live in a big Muslim country and trust most people will simply reject free masonry from the moment they hear the name.. So I guess unless you provide full details it will be hard to answer it.

Comment: @HaLaBi, I'm sorry, it would be almost impossible to provide full details.  Imagine if I asked you to provide full details of Islam.  However Freemasonry is not a religion.  If you do not know why they would reject free masonry, then please post, else you do not have enough information to even comment - no disrespect intended.

Comment: @DanAndrews It seems that you want a full answer based on very little details.. which is impossible. Can you at least post the oath to be taken when joining free masonry? I think that will be helpful.

Comment: @HaLaBi No disrespect, maybe you're not the best person to answer the question.  Thanks for trying.  Maybe there is someone else who has more information about it being acceptable or not for a Muslim to join Masonry.  Thanks again.  Clearly you cannot answer the question - but that doesn't mean that someone else cannot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know little about the Freemasons in particular, so this answer is geared towards fraternal organizations in general.  Regardless of the goals, rituals and creeds of any individual fraternity, they almost always promise a fellowship of mutual acceptance and support for their members; a "brotherhood" as it were.

Muslims are not forbidden from socializing and just generally associating with non-Muslims (assuming of course that they're not actively fighting the Muslims or mocking God's Word).  Joining a fraternity, on the other hand, is a different story as God says in the Qur'an,

> **Let not believers take disbelievers as *'awliyaa'* (أَوْلِيَاءَ) rather than believers. And whoever [of you] does that has nothing with Allah , except when taking precaution against them in prudence. And Allah warns you of Himself, and to Allah is the [final] destination.** ([Qur'an 3:28](http://quran.com/3/28))

The word *'awliyaa'* (أَوْلِيَاءَ) does not really have a single translation in English; various major translations of the above *ayah* have interpreted it as "friends", "guides", "guardians", "counselors", "patrons", "supporters", "helpers" and "allies".

Each and every one of these translations can also describe the members of a fraternity.

Rather, God proclaims that the Muslim community forms its own brotherhood, when He says,

> **The believing men and believing women are *'awliyaa'* (أَوْلِيَاءَ) of one another. They enjoin what is right and forbid what is wrong and establish prayer and give zakah and obey Allah and His Messenger. Those - Allah will have mercy upon them. Indeed, Allah is Exalted in Might and Wise.** ([Qur'an 9:71](http://quran.com/9/71))

As such, if a fraternity is organized by and for Muslims, upholding God's Law and supporting each other along the straight path, it would be acceptable (albeit a bit redundant since we're supposed to be doing all that anyway).

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer.  Freemasonry does not replace God's Law nor does it prohibit a person from following one's religion.  Most concerns are generally about believers associating with non-believers of the same religion.  To me, we believe in the same God, the God of Abraham.  We just worship him differently.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

I do not have very much knowledge of the freemason organization, but my answer is based on the information you have provided.

In islam we follow the rule that everything is halal (permissable) unless it has been stated otherwise.

> And why should you not eat of that upon which the name of Allah has been mentioned while He has explained in detail to you what He has forbidden you, excepting that to which you are compelled. And indeed do many lead [others] astray through their [own] inclinations without knowledge. Indeed, your Lord - He is most knowing of the transgressors.6:119
> And leave what is apparent of sin and what is concealed thereof. Indeed, those who earn [blame for] sin will be recompensed for that which they used to commit.6:120

This verse from the quran is a message from allah that is saying not to forbid yourself from doing things that were not said to be prohibited. Allah has explained to us what is prohibited, we should not commit what is prohibited, nor should we stray away from what isnt.

we are allowed to interact with others, be in agreements with others and be freinds with people of other religions. We are also encourged to help those in need with charity.

> [2:177]  Righteousness is not turning your faces towards the east or the west. Righteous are those who believe in GOD, the Last Day, the angels, the scripture, and the prophets; and they give the money, cheerfully, to the relatives, the orphans, the needy, the traveling alien, the beggars, and to free the slaves; and they observe the Contact Prayers (Salat) and give the obligatory charity (Zakat); and they keep their word whenever they make a promise; and they steadfastly persevere in the face of persecution, hardship, and war. These are the truthful; these are the righteous
>
> 5:85 Strongest among men in enmity to the Believers wilt thou find the Jews and Pagans; and nearest among them in *love* to the Believers wilt thou find those who say, "We are Christians": Because amongst these are men devoted to learning and men who have renounced the world, and they are not arrogant.

the verses above explain that the strongest relashonships muslims will have to other religions would be jews and christians because within their religions they have people who are devoted to learning and are not arrogent, both being highley apprectiated characteristics in islam. The verses also demonstrate that not only is giving to charity allowed, but it is honored in the quran those who give to charity are being called *righteous* by Allah.

But we are also advised not to make agreements with those who are conspiering against islam or muslims.

> Let not believers take disbelievers as allies rather than believers. And whoever [of you] does that has nothing with Allah , except when taking precaution against them in prudence. And Allah warns you of Himself, and to Allah is the [final] destination."

in conclusion, there is no evidence that a fraternity is prohibited in islam. However i cannot speak on behalf of the freemasons due to the limited information given on their secret organization, i do not know if any haram (prohibited) activity is being carried out within the fraternity and its members.

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer.  IMHO, Muslims should join groups which allow communication between religions (any group - not just Freemasonry) to show that the views of some are not shared among all (extremists).

Answer (score 3):

I guess it may go political here, but I will present my ideas here and moderators may judge my ideas:

well it is a common belief for Arab and maybe Muslims, as I read from many books, that the main goal of the Masons is to rebuild the temple of King Solomon peace be upon him, and to establish the state of Israel, well this contradicts with what Muslims and Arab believe in the rights of Palestinians in the land of Palestine ( which is considered Israel to a lot of non-Arab, non-Muslim),

well another point that Harun Yahya (not only him but a lot or other scholars)  presents, he thinks that Masony was created as opponent to religions, you can see those links (http://www.harunyahya.com/en/books/677/Global_Freemasonry/chapter/1910, http://harunyahya.com/en/Makaleler/5412/The_dark_philosophy_of_atheist_freemasonry)

I know that this is the main problem regarding Masonry from the point view of an Arabic or Muslim person

Comment: +1 Thank you for your answer.  However I can assure you that Masons wish to do no such thing - at least not together as a group.  There may be some Masons in some country that I do not know about - but I would be surprised.  I thank you for your answer as this is a valid reason why some Arabic Muslims would dislike Masonry.

Comment: @DanAndrews
you know because of bad communications and the limited knowledge about such topic in the Arabic area a lot of unproved information spread, we can't know which is true and which is false

Comment: You are right.  For the same reason some Christians believe rumors that are not true.  All I can do is speak the truth with God as my witness.  Having friends who are of different religions allows you to look at your own religion.  It definitely allows you to learn about other religions and respect them.  I may not have studied Islam as much as I have w/o it.  Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: regarding your edit which adds a link suggesting that Masonry was created as opponent to religions: I find that hard to believe from what I know.  We allow no atheists to join (it's a rule).  You MUST believe in an all powerful God.  Your religion is your choice.  Oh, and we're taught to become better "creatures for the creator"

Comment: @DanAndrews You might find it hard to believe. But, according to reports I get, freemasons have such ideology. You might want to confirm it. 
They say:  It is not enough for us to prevail over the religious people and their places of worship, rather our basic goal is to wipe them out of existence. 

Minutes of the World Masonic Conference, 1903 CE, p. 102.

Comment: It says in the Masonic Grand Lodge (1922, p. 98): We will strengthen the freedom of individual thought with all the powers at our disposal, and we will declare war against the real enemy of man, which is religion.

Comment: @Ershad I have never heard such things.  As in all groups some people with their own beliefs may say something.  That something may be recorded and quoted later and it does not represent the common belief.  I am sure the same is true for Muslims.  I will research the quotes which you have provided.  Thank you

Comment: @Ershad please consider reading this: http://www.freemasons-freemasonry.com/islam_freemasonry.html

Answer (score -1):

Freemasonry is NOT a religion but is a Luciferian replacement seeking to supplant all faiths.  We know this from the mouth of a Freemason.
No Christian is permitted to join such an organisation, though many Freemason heretics exist in high office within the organised church.  Their state of heresy frees all Christians from flowing them as they have their office falsely.